# Prevent transitive dependencies from SBT subproject

Tags: scala, sbt, transitive-dependency

I have an SBT (v0.13) project with multiple subprojects with the following dependencies. root -> projectA -> projectB -> projectC. Like so:

```
lazy val projectA = (project in file("projectA")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(projectB)
lazy val projectB = (project in file("projectB")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(projectC)
lazy val projectC = (project in file("projectC")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

As I have it now, projectA can reference an API in projectC because of transitive dependency. How can I declare a dependency on projectB without pulling projectC classes into the classpath?

I have come across solutions using `notTransitive()` in libraryDependencies. Like so:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "groupId" %% "artifactId" % "version" notTransitive()
)
```

Even if I do get to declare each one of projectC's dependencies this way (yuck!!!) projectC's APIs themselves are still available to projectA.

Appreciate any ideas on how I could do something like this (*pseudo code*)?

```
lazy val projectA = (project in file("projectA")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(projectB).notTransitive() // pseudo-code
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is possible.  What you can do is remove the `dependsOn(projectC)` from `projectB` and add `projectC` as a library dependency.  You should then be able to use `notTransitive()`.

That being said, I'd recommend evaluating why you feel the need to exclude `projectC`.  If `projectC` is providing libraries which are required upstream, consider breaking those out into their own project which `projectB` and `projectC` could both depend on.